# How to install lodash.filter using npm?

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-install

I need to install `lodash.filter` to my Expo (React Native) project.

How should I do it using npm?

1.
npm i -g npm
npm i --save lodash.filter

2. ```
     npm i --save lodash.filter
   ```

I do not understand what `npm i -g npm` (it's updating something, but I think it will destroy my project).

Comment: i from install (not the same than -i) and -g from globally. Run npm -v / node -v to know your compatibility with the package

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ npm i -g npm
$ npm i --save lodash
```

you can use second command.

`npm i` is the alias for the `npm install` and `-g` means `gloabal`
The `-g or --global` argument will cause npm to install the package globally rather than locally
`npm install` (in package directory, no arguments):

Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
Just follow the command that are written in documentation it will be fine
The `--save` option instructed NPM to include the package inside of the dependencies section of your package.json automatically, thus saving you an additional step.